# Collapse does not work using ng-bootstrap

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I am using Angular and ng-bootstrap for the first time and I am having a problem with the Collapse component. All I am trying to do is to collapse / expand a div using Bootstrap. My issue is that the `button` is not working and the `a` (link) is actually navigating away (taking href as a literal hyperlink to http://#collapseExample ! It is as if the site does not recognize bootstrap, but the `ngb-accordion` actually works.

I am puzzled as to what I may be doing wrong, any help would be much appreciated.

The code is taken from an official bootstrap site
(https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/) though it is possible that Bootstrap 4 and 5 are different - I am using the latest version of Angular and ngbootstrap.

```
<p>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false"
        aria-controls="collapseExample">
        Link with href
    </a>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample"
        aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
        Button with data-target
    </button>
</p>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
    <div class="card card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim
        keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: Here is some additional information:

I have `"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^12.1.2",` in the dependencies section of my package.json.

I also have `@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';` in my styles.css.

app.module.ts has `import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';` where NgbModule is added in the imports section of the @NgModule declaration.

Comment: Are you sure you have imported the bootstrap css and js files properly?

Comment: I revised my answer to respond. I am not sure if there is a js file that I should be importing above and beyond how I installed the package on my project. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ngb-bootstrap is **not** bootstrap

Ngb-bootstrap is a library of Angular components that use **only** bootstrap.css (nor bootstrap.bundle.min.js nor popper.min.js nor bootstrap.min.js)

So, to use ngb-bootstrap you should install as is showed in the [docs](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started), download the bootstrap.min.css (e.g. you download in a folder css/bootstrap) and add in angular.json the .css in

```
"styles": [
      "src/styles.css",
      "css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css"
    ],
```

Then use a collapse as it's shoed in the [docs of ng-boostrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/accordion/examples), not in the docs of bootstrap

Comment: Thanks, I did the installation as it was in the docs. I have given additional info about my project's setup in the original question. Although your response didn't exactly give me the answer, based on your recommendation I found the correct collapse example at: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/collapse/examples. Thanks for your help!